# How to eliminate vocal fry on bridges?

Tags: voice, bridge

my sound becomes squeaky(vocal fry) on bridges. How do I eliminate it?

Comment: What do you mean - on bridges?

Comment: @Tim transition from chest to mix and then from mix to head

Comment: Don't worry about it. Some of my digital instruments on GarageBand produce similar "artifacts" on abrupt pitch or pitch group changes. Sometimes I actually work those into a track on purpose, effectively using a glitch or unexpected, probably unwanted behavior in the system as a "feature".